# Swift: Message filter extension not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a message filter application.

I created a php API that sends me a response. 
Here is my php code:

```
class ServerResponse {
    public $filter = false;
}
​
$serverResponse = new ServerResponse();
​
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
​
$sender = $data['query']['sender'];
$message = $data['query']['message']['text'];
​
if (strpos($message, 'code') !== false) {
    $serverResponse->filter = true;
} else {
    $serverResponse->filter = false;
}
​
echo json_encode($serverResponse);
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_mms_message_filtering), the API is POST type and it works with this payload:

```
{
    "_version": 1,
    "query": {
        "sender": "0580000000",
        "message": {
            "text": "This is a message code"
        }
    },
    "app": {
        "version": "1.1"
    }
}
```

The API worked and returned me the following JSON data:

```
{
    "filter": true
}
```

I have also uploaded this to my server as described by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains) when setting up an app’s Associated Domains

```
{  
    "messagefilter": {  
        "apps": ["MyTeamID.com.****.SMS-TEst.MessageFilter",
                 "MyTeamID.com.****.SMS-TEst"]  
    }  
}
```

For my app's target, I added `messagefilter:myDomain.io` under **Signing & Capabilities > Associated Domains**.

My info.plist:

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ILMessageFilterExtensionNetworkURL</key>
            <string>https://myDomain.io/mickaeltest</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.identitylookup.message-filter</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).MessageFilterExtension</string>
    </dict>
```

In my message filter extension, I have the following code:

```
context.deferQueryRequestToNetwork() { (networkResponse, error) in
                let response = ILMessageFilterQueryResponse()
                response.action = .none

                if let networkResponse = networkResponse {
                    // If we received a network response, parse it to determine an action to return in our response.
                    response.action = self.action(for: networkResponse)
                } else {
                    NSLog("Error deferring query request to network: \(String(describing: error))")
                }

                completion(response)
            }
```

However, NetworkResponse is `nil` with error description `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.IdentityLookup.error.messagefilter error 3.)`

What have I forgotten?

Comment: Where did you upload `apple-app-site-association` file to? It should be inside `.well-known` directory. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

This error is due to this reason.

```
 /// Extension's containing app is not authorized to allow extension to defer network requests to the host specified in the URL of the extension's Info.plist.
    ILMessageFilterErrorNetworkURLUnauthorized = 3,
```

You can fix this error by adding your domain as a associated domain in you main app settings

In your case it will `messagefilter:myDomain.io`

[image]

Your apple-app-site-association file should be like this. You can get your team ID from your apple account.

```
{  
    "messagefilter": {  
        "apps": ["89N85A6AAQ.com.****.SMS-TEst.MessageFilter",
                 "89N85A6AAQ.com.****.SMS-TEst"]  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,add the key 'App Transport Security Settings' in main app's info.plist file solve this problem